# Can' t resolve module - Material-UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, material-ui

I am getting error on trying to import a component from 'Material-Ui'. 
Actually i am working with React and Webpack.
I am wanna use "Card" component (http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/card).

Card import on my .js is like documentation ->

```
   import {Card} from 'material-ui/Card'
```

This is my Webpack log:

> Cannot resolve module 'react/lib/reactProdInvariant' in
>   .../node_modules/material-ui/ReactFragment.

Any idea?

Comment: Try `import Card from 'material-ui/lib/card';`

Comment: I believe If you specify the path in the from part you dont need curly brackets, so If I were you I would try `import Card from 'material-ui/Card'` or `import {Card} from 'material-ui'`

Comment: I put curly braces becouse i only wanted to import just Card. Also i am getting error importing from 'material-ui/lib/card'. That directory doesn't exists.

Comment: and what about `material-ui/Card/Card`? [Reference](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/tree/master/src/Card)

Comment: Getting same error :/

Comment: So, do you check if you have some broken dependencies between `material-ui` and `react`?

Comment: I recently re-install material-ui package and get:

UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY: react@15.0.0
react-dom@15.0.0
react-tap-event-plugin@2.0.1

Does it mean something?

Comment: @FacundoLaRocca Solved. Just you said, it was dependencies problem. I didn' t got last React version. I updated all, and i solve it. Thanks man!

Comment: Glad to help!!! Would you mind to accept my answer and vote it up please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be some broken dependencies between `material-ui` and `react`. I think you should update your dependencies.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

I think that the card is a default export of material-ui/Card. Try importing it without brackets.
Here are some examples:

```
import MuiSnackbar from '@material-ui/core/Snackbar';
import Slide from '@material-ui/core/Slide';
import CloseIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Close';
import InfoIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Info';
```

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 0):

There are broken dependencies between material-ui and react

Try doing - `yarn add @material-ui/core`

Worked for me in my case it was @material-ui/core/chippedInput that was missing.